# How can I make a cell in Excel to change colour according to the value of other cell?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

What I'm trying to do is a tv shows spreadsheet. I have a column of the tv show name and other with the percentage of episodes watched.

I've put conditional format in the percentage column in order to change color from red to yellow to green if the percentage is less than 40%, between 41 and 75% and more than 76%. Now I want to put the name of the show changing color automatically like the other column.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXoOL.gif

In this case, I want that "30 Rock" changes color to yellow like the percentage.

Thanks in adavance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to format a cell based on another cell's value:

1. Highlight the cell(s) you want formatting applied to.
2. In Excel's **Home** ribbon, select: **Conditional Formatting** > **New Rule**
3. Select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**
4. Fill in the formula that determines whether formatting gets applied. (If the formula evaluates to `True`, it gets applied.) In the example image below, this uses `$D` to keep column D as the one that always determines the format, but no `$` with the row number, so that changes per row.
5. Select the format to be applied and hit OK.

[image]

Full instructions here with more detail:

[Excel University: Excel Conditional Formatting Based on Another Cell](http://www.excel-university.com/excel-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell/)